# pyplot неправильный порядок отметок на оси y

Tags: python, matplotlib

Добрый вечер! Я использую библиотеку pyplot для визуализации сигнала ЭЭГ. На входе есть значения по оси Y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ys = open("input.txt").read().split(",")
xs = [i + 1 for i in range(len(ys))]

l = plt.plot(xs, ys)

plt.show()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что значения на оси Y идут не в порядке возрастания, а в лексикографическом порядке. Скриншоты:
[image: После 139 идет 14]
[image: После 255 идет 32]

Также был бы очень благодарен за информацию, как масштабировать только ось X - у меня 50000 точек, и pyplot сжимает их в маленькое окошко, очень охватить взглядом несколько значений.

Answer (score 1):

У вас массив `ys` содержит строки, преобразуйте их в числа:

```
ys = list(map(int, ys))
```

(функция [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) ожидает аргументами два массива, в которых будут находиться числа)

---

Про масштабирование:

- задать размер фигуры можно, передав в метод [`plt.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) параметр `figsize`:

  ```
  plt.figure(figsize=(ширина, высота))
  ```
- ещё при необходимости можно обрезать график по координатам, методами [`plt.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) или [`plt.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html):

  ```
  plt.xlim((x_минимальная, x_максимальная))
  plt.ylim((y_минимальная, y_максимальная))
  ```